# Refreshing iframe error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, reload

I am using an iframe in a div block and trying to change its src through a button click with the following code.

```
function helloClick(){
            var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeDiv");
            iframe.src = "hello_world";
            iframe.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
}
```

The hello_world file is located in the same folder as the file where iframe is defined. I get the following error message every time I click on the button.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: if iframe is on another domain you can't access `contentDocument` thus you get that error. Is it on another domain than page it is displayed in?

Comment: @charlietfl No its not on another domain. I am building a test website on my local server and both the iframe file and src file are in the same location.

Comment: use onload handler and try inside that

Comment: Does your file has any extension like "hello_world.php" or "hello_world.c" etc ?

Comment: Oh! its a basic html file. I didnt put any extensions on it but its no problem for a browser.

Comment: You doesnt need to reload iframe because it will reload on `src` change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code snippet

```
function helloClick(){
            var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeDiv");
            iframe.src = "hello_world";
            iframe.src = iframe.src;
}
```

It should help you.

Comment: Most welcome :) You can accept answer in case it is useful to you.